# Style not applying to Menu Items

Tags: android, xml, colors, menuitem, android-styles

I am trying to apply a theme on my application. Everything is working fine except the menu that I am inflating with a display_menu.xml file. What I am doing wrong here?

**My styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme.Dark">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorBackground</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorBackground</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondaryInverse">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="cardStyle">@style/CardView.Dark</item>
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyApp.PopupMenu</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyApp.PopupMenu" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearanceListItem">@style/MyText</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyText">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

**My display_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        android:title="@string/action_refresh"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

**I'm inflating it like**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.display_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

My menu item is displaying like this:

[image]

This is the drawable I am trying to put in background:

[image]

I am trying to give the background of menu item as my colorPrimary** and text color as `textColorPrimary`

Comment: as you are not using holo theme so why you apply parent of popup menu as android:Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow,

Comment: So what should I change it to?

Comment: see the answer, hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

> This Helps me

**Add popupMenu style to ur AppTheme:**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

**manifest.xml:**

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
.............
</application>
```

Comment: After hours of frustration, I switched to Floating Action Button. Thanks anyways.